# The controller doesn't work when I use 'ng-app'

Tags: angularjs

Here is a snippet:

```
<!document html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>First</title>
        <script src="D:\Coding\angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="FirstController">
            <input id="Text1" type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
            <div>{{user.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function FirstController($scope){
                $scope.user = {name: ""};
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Open the .html file with Chrome, the '{{user.name}}' shows on the screen. I think the {{}} position should be the same with the textbox content, what's wrong?

Comment: Many replies suggest me define a module and give the `ng-app` attribute a value like `ng-app = "blablabla"`. Yes this will work and I have tried it at first. But the real point is the angular.js version, I am using 1.6 and it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using angular version below 1.3 it should work

**DEMO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.js"></script>
</head>

 <body>
        <div ng-controller="FirstController">
            <input id="Text1" type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
            <div>{{user.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function FirstController($scope){
                $scope.user = {name: "test"};
            };
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. How could you remember the version update, I'm so surprised:)

Comment: @T.skyone because i have answered same kind of question before. :) upvote if it has helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like this :

```
<ng-app="Your Module Name ">
```

In controller write

```
var app=angular.module("your module name (can be anything)",[]).controller("myCtrl", function("your dependencies "){});
```

Hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

In the ng-app attribute you need to add app name like as ng-app="myApp"

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add like this

```
ng-app="yourappname"
```

Refer [ng-app directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) in documentation